# how to sort a vector of pairs?

Tags: c++, templates, sorting

I am trying to sort a vector of `pair<int, T>` (where T is the templated value type of the class) and codeblocks is giving me massive amounts of errors i dont understand why. is there there some special syntax required to sort `vector<pair<int, T> >`? i did make the comparison function, which did not use T at all

here's the code

```
  bool sortlevel(pair<int, T> a, pair<int, T> b){
    return a.first < b.first;
  }

  void get_level(Node<T> * root, vector <pair<int, T> > & order, int level = 0){
    // changes the tree to a vector
    if (root){
        order.push_back(pair(level, root -> value));
        get_level(root -> left, order, level + 1);
        get_level(root -> right, order, level + 1);
    }
  }

  void level_order(ostream & ostr ) {
    vector<pair<int, T> > order;
    get_level(root_, order);
    sort(order.begin(), order.end(), sortlevel);
    int max_level = order[order.size() - 1] -> first;
    int x = 0;
    int current_level = order[x] -> first;
    while (x < order.size()){
        for(int y = 0; y < current_level - x; y++)
            cout << "\t";
        while (order[x] -> first == current_level){
            cout << order[x] -> second << " ";
            x++;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please show the code surrounding the area where you are getting the errors.  Also edit your post to include the error text.

Comment: What errors? What's your code? You probably just need a comparator for your `T`.

Comment: @calcrypto: We'll just guess, then, shall we?!

Comment: I fixed your code - see below.  There were a bunch of bugs but the sort part is actually OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code didn't compile but when I was trying to make it compile I noticed you probably want:

```
order.push_back(std::make_pair(level, root -> value));
```

Also:

```
int max_level = order[order.size() - 1]. first;
```

This fixed version of yours **compiles** for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class T
{};

template <class T> class Node
{
public:
T value;
Node<T>* left;
Node<T>* right;
};

Node<T>* root_;

bool sortlevel(pair<int, T> a, pair<int, T> b){
    return a.first < b.first;
  }

  void get_level(Node<T> * root, vector <pair<int, T> > & order, int level = 0){
    // changes the tree to a vector
    if (root){
        order.push_back(std::make_pair(level, root -> value));
        get_level(root -> left, order, level + 1);
        get_level(root -> right, order, level + 1);
    }
  }

  void level_order(ostream & ostr ) {
    vector<pair<int, T> > order;
    get_level(root_, order);
    sort(order.begin(), order.end(), sortlevel);
    int max_level = order[order.size() - 1]. first;
    int x = 0;
    int current_level = order[x].first;
    while (x < order.size()){
        for(int y = 0; y < current_level - x; y++)
            cout << "\t";
        while (order[x]. first == current_level){
//            cout << order[x]. second << " ";
            x++;
        }
    }
  }
```

**This part came before the full code was posted but may still be useful to someone trying to figure out sort so I'll keep it in**:
Generally for sorting you may need to provide a way of comparing the pairs, e.g. see here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

If you use the sort algorithm it will work automagically for anything that has the less than operator defined but not for other types.

std::pair should provide a default less than operator so perhaps there is another issue - can we see the code?  As Tomalak notes, that is probably because you have no way of comparing T's.

Comment: Pairs already have comparators. More likely he needs a comparator for `T`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes. I see that now.

Answer (score 2):

Provide your own comparison function (or functor) as the last argument to `sort`. Your comparison should take the first of the pair and compare it.

for instance:

```
template<typename T>
bool myfunction (const pair<int, T>& i, const pair<int, T>& j)
{ 
   return (i.first < j.first); 
}

sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction<ActualType>);
```

Comment: Why? Why not just introduce a comparator for `T<T` into scope?

Comment: `std::pair` overload does `(_Left.first < _Right.first ||
  !(_Right.first < _Left.first) && _Left.second < _Right.second)` that may not be what he wants.

Comment: Maybe not but yours does _not_ fit the strict weak ordering criteria!

Answer (score 1):

If you start with:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct T {
   T(int x) : x(x) {};

   int x;
};

int main() {
   std::vector<std::pair<int, T> > v;

   std::pair<int, T> a = std::make_pair(0, T(42));
   std::pair<int, T> b = std::make_pair(1, T(36));

   v.push_back(a);
   v.push_back(b);

   std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Add a comparator for `T`, that `std::pair<int, T>`'s default-generated comparator will invoke:

```
struct T {
   T(int x) : x(x) {};
   bool operator<(const T& other) const {
      return x < other.x;
   }

   int x;
};
```

- [The errors you were probably getting](http://ideone.com/V4uOE)
- [The good result](http://ideone.com/pVFSz)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like these are member functions of a class template. If that is the case, then `sortlevel` will need to be static (or a non-member) in order to be used as the comparator in `std::sort()`.

Also, you've written e.g. `order[x]->first` in a few places, when it should be `order[x].first`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're using `T` you need to make sure it is in a class or a function with a `template<typename T>` before it.

in your code:

- you need `template<typename T>` before the definition of `sortlevel`, `get_level` and `level_order`
- when calling `sort` you need to classify `sortlevel<T>`.
- when calling these function, call them with the actual type.